# How to use <![CDATA[]]> in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have use  in XSLT variable look like:

```
<xsl:variable name="ShortDescription" select="str[@name = 'ShortDescription']"/>
<!--Short Description field-->
       <xsl:if test="$ShortDescription !=''">

        <shortdescription><![CDATA[ <xsl:value-of select="$ShortDescription" disable-output-escaping="no"/> ]]></shortdescription>

       </xsl:if>
```

But its display as a text not a value of `$ShortDescription` variable and output look like:

```
<shortdescription>
&lt;xsl:value-of select="$ShortDescription" disable-output-escaping="no"/&gt;
</shortdescription>
```

expected output look like:

```
<shortdescription>
<![CDATA[Maximum Power: 520 W<br/>+12V Rails: Dual<br/>]]>
</shortdescription>
```

How to use `<![CDATA[]]>` in XSLT?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @CédricBignon i have updated my problem with expected output

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add CDATA to an xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534255/add-cdata-to-an-xml-file)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

XSLT is XML so of course you can use a CDATA section in XSLT code, as you have done. However it rather seems you want the output of the XSLT code to contain a CDATA section for the `shortdescription` contents, in that case you need

```
<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="shortdescription"/>
```

And the XSLT would simply stay as

```
<shortdescription><xsl:value-of select="$ShortDescription"/></shortdescription>
```

Comment: Note however that (a) this will only work if the output of the transformation is being serialized by the XSLT processor (and not being sent, say, to a DOM tree or to another transformation); and (b) the requirement is misguided; someone who asks for output text to be enclosed in CDATA sections has a poor understanding of XML.

Comment: @MichaelKay what would be valid usescases for cdata?

Comment: @Dragas, I would say that putting markup like HTML markup that is not well-formed so it has to be escaped to be stored inside XML benefits from being put in a CDATA section as that way you can read it well (e.g. `<p>This is a paragraph with <strong>text</strong>`) while having to escape e.g. `<p>` as `&lt;p&gt;` makes no difference to the XSLT/XML parser or serializer but makes it hard for human consumers to read the HTML data embedded in XML.

Comment: One place I use it is in test catalogs: `<test><query><![CDATA[<e>{2+2}</e>]]></query><expect><![CDATA[<e>4</e>]]></expect></test>` You could do exactly the same thing escaping the angle brackets with `&lt;` and `&gt;` but it's less readable.