# Special characters in BPEL

Tags: xslt-1.0, soa, cdata, bpel

This is regarding the common problem we face in Middleware( Oracle SOA 11g). We have one source value like "SEBẪSTIN" but while reading this value the final output value is appearing as "SEB�STIN"

yes..I know, I can use CDATA for not parsing the value. But it is not working.

I have referred to the following post. But no luck.
 [How to use <![CDATA[]]> in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400067/how-to-use-cdata-in-xslt)

Could you please let me know the correct syntax using CDATA. My xslt tag looks like this

```
 <ns2:Firstname>
        <xsl:value-of select="imp1:FIRSTNAME"/>
      </ns2:Firstname>
```

OR

do we have any other option to handle this character.

*version details* :
Oracle SOA 11g
Jdeveloper: 11.1.1.7.0
BPEL: 2.0
XSLT: 1.0

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Abhi

Comment: What is the character encoding at source ? I guess encoding in your BPEL is getting changed. Therefore you are getting the junk character in output. You need to make sure to use consistent encoding from source to destination.

Comment: Hi,       Although I did not get the proper solution but I get a way to process the file. I have used the following  `Normalizer.normalize(outputString, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");`  where outputString=full file  . This code changes "SEBẪSTIN" to "SEBASTIN" ... yes I know it is not the exact solution because we are altering the data.  Please share any way or method to handle this scenario if you know.