# Does the CDATA slows the xslt transformation in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xalan, xpath-1.0

I use XPATH 1.0 and XSLT 1.0. I am wondering if the following code

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@name='some'"><![CDATA[one]]></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><![CDATA[two]]></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

has a difference in case of performance with

```
 <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@name='some'"><xsl:value-of select="'one'"/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="'two'"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

if we know that there must be **no** need for some special symbols in the select?
Is it a good practice to use `<![CDATA[one]]>`. Or its use decrease the xslt compilation time, or it is easy to read??

Comment: I don't know about performance, but I would use `xsl:text` to output literal text. Or, if you have no whitespace to worry about, just write the literal text, e.g. `<xsl:when test="@name='some'">one</xsl:when>`.

Comment: Why do you need to use a CDATA all, why can't you use `xsl:when test="@name='some'">one</xsl:when>`? As for performance, just measure, the XSLT processor does not deal with the CDATA at all, it will have been parsed into a text node by the underlying XML parser anyway. Whether Xalan is smart enough to optimize a constant `<xsl:value-of select="'one'"/>` I don't know.

Comment: There is never any need to use CDATA sections around text that includes no special characters such as `<` and `&`. But it's unlikely to impose more than a nanosecond or two in processing cost, and that will be a one-off cost during stylesheet compilation.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if there's a performance improvement it is not so significant to justify your first example.

In this case I would pay more attention about maintenance and readability as your second example. With this solution if you want change how elements have to be rendered (as cdata or not) you can use the attribute cdata-section-elements in the output element.

Here's a good example about it [How to use cdata in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400067/how-to-use-cdata-in-xslt)

Comment: @Martin Honnen I've seen right now that the accepted answer of the question I've cited is yours :)