# Need to parse XML with html elements

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, cdata

I have an xml file like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Book>
  <Title>Ulysses</Title>
  <Author>James <b>Joyce</b></Author>
</Book>
```

I need to parse this using Java into a pojo like

```
title="Ulysses"
author="James <b>Joyce</b>"
```

In other words, I need the html or possible custom xml tags to remain as plain text rather than xml elements, when parsing.

I can't edit the XML at all but it would be ok for me to create a custom xslt file to transform the xml.

I've got the following Java code for using xslt to assist with the reading of the xml,

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source stylesheetSource = new StreamSource(new File(stylesheetPathname).getAbsoluteFile());
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(stylesheetSource);
    Source inputSource = new StreamSource(new File(inputPathname).getAbsoluteFile());
    Result outputResult = new StreamResult(new File(outputPathname).getAbsoluteFile());
    transformer.transform(inputSource, outputResult);
```

This does apply my xslt to the file which is written out but I can't come up with the correct xslt to do it. I had a look at [Add CDATA to an xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534255/add-cdata-to-an-xml-file) but this does not work for me.

Essentially, I believe I want the file to look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Book>
  <Title>Ulysses</Title>
  <Author><![CDATA[James <b>Joyce</b>]]></Author>
</Book>
```

Then I can extract 
`"James <b>Joyce</b>"`. I tried the approach suggested here: [Add CDATA to an xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534255/add-cdata-to-an-xml-file)
But it did not work for me.

I used the following xslt:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

<xsl:template match="Author">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>    
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and this produced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  Ulysses
  <Author><![CDATA[
<b>Joyce</b>]]></Author>
```

Can you please help with this? I want the original document to be written out in it's entirety but with the CDATA surrounding everything within the author element.
Thanks

Comment: What does "it did not work for me" look like?  XML with markup in it is not proper XML.  You can escape those magic characters or wrap in CDATA.  No other choices.

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 3.0 as supported by Saxon 9.8 HE (available on Maven and Sourceforge) you can use XSLT as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="Author"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="Author">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="serialize(node())"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for your attempt, you basically need to "implement" the identity transformation template concisely written in XSLT 3.0 as `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` as a template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

in XSLT 1.0 so that those nodes not handled by more specialized template (like the one for `Author` elements) are recursively copied through.

Then, with the copy-of selecting all child nodes `node()` and not only the element nodes `*` you get

```
<xsl:template match="Author">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>    
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I've tried your XSLT 1.0 example and it now behaves as expected except that there are some line break differences.Any ideas on how to address this? I tried adding the input/output here in this comment but it doesn't display well.
 Thank you very much for your response, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Does that happen with or without `xsl:output` `indent="yes"`? I would try without if whitespace should be preserved.

Comment: I tried both setting indent="no" and removing it altogether but the result was the same.

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/naZXpXZ looks fine to me as far as the elements are concerned. I am not sure what to suggest to tune the indentation or line breaks other than playing with the settings. You might want to ask a new question with the details about the output you get and the one you want, with details as to which transformer you use, perhaps then someone has an idea to improve the approach.

Comment: I'm noticing that this approach doesn't copy attributes for the elements that get CDATA added, I appreciate that this was not spelled out in my question but I am wondering if you know how I can address this? I tried changing
<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>    to 
<xsl:copy-of select="node() | @*"/>    
but the result was the same.

Comment: If the `Author` element can have attributes you want to copy as attributes to the result then see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't using a simple html/xml parser like Jsoup a better way of solving this?
Using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) you can try something like this:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"
                + "<Book>\n"
                + "  <Title>Ulysses</Title>\n"
                + "  <Author>James <b>Joyce</b></Author>\n"
                + "</Book>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
        Elements books = doc.select("Book");
        for(Element e: books){
            Book b = new Book(e.select("Title").html(),e.select("Author").html());
            System.out.println(b.title);
            System.out.println(b.author);
        }
    }
    public static class Book{
        String title;
        String author;

        public Book(String title, String author) {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This does achieve what I'm looking for in this case but if I add more html it is altered when parsed by Jsoup, what I need is for the exact text between the element to be reproduced without being changed.