# How to get <![CDATA[ ]]> in the output - XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a sample XML, wherein the final output through XSL should contain  within the URL.

For example:

```
<xml>

            <url>

            https://example.com?adults=1&av-seleccion-grupo=on&babies=0&children=0&dateFrom[0]

            </url>
</xml>
```

Expected output through XSLT is:

```
    <url>

  <![CDATA[https://example.com?adults=1&av-seleccion-grupo=on&babies=0&children=0&dateFrom[0]]]>

    </url>
```

I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<xsl:variable name="URL1"> <xsl:value-of select="url" /></xsl:variable>

<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="URL1"/>
```

Which I found on another thread, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534255/add-cdata-to-an-xml-file

Comment: Using `cdata-section-elements="url"` should work and does for me at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbf, the only important thing is that the XSLT processor needs to be in charge of serializing the result of the XSLT transformation. So if you still have problems then you need to explain and show how exactly you run the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly as Martin Honnen has written in his comment, you should use `cdata-section-elements="url"` with xsl:output. Output element set your desired output document format, not your input data or variable name. So you have to use the element's name of the expected output. 
[See XSLT Output element on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_output.asp)