# Add CDATA to a Node Value in a loop

Tags: c#, xslt, cdata

** Updated the output **
I am trying to add a <![CDATA[...]] to a value node that is being generated inside a loop. 
I am using XSLT & C#.net.
I have tried a couple of things including 
[Add CDATA to an xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534255/add-cdata-to-an-xml-file)
but none seems to be working so far.
I even tried adding it literally but, as expected it did not work out. 
Can anyone please help me in this.

Here's how my node is being generated

```
<xsl:for-each select="$OLifE/">
                    <DataPoint>
                      <Name>Carrier.Requirements<xsl:if test="$NumberOfPayments > 1"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:if></Name>
                      <Value>Here is the response text</Value>
</DataPoint>
```

My expected output is

```
<DataPoint>
    <Name>Carrier.Requirements1</Name>
    <Value><![CDATA[Here is the response text]]</Value>
</DataPoint>
<DataPoint>
    <Name>Carrier.Requirements2</Name>
    <Value><![CDATA[Here is the response text]]</Value>
</DataPoint>
<DataPoint>
    <Name>Carrier.Requirements3</Name>
    <Value><![CDATA[Here is the response text]]</Value>
</DataPoint>
```

Please let me know in case any further information is required.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including an input and the expected output.

Comment: Still no input. And your expected output does not have any CDATA - so it's not clear what your issue is.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: when you say input, what do you mean? I think the input is the values coming from the loop in the first code section.

Comment: The input to XSLT is an XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="Value"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <DataPoint>
                <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Carrier.Requirements', position())"/>
                </Name>
                <Value>Here is the response text</Value>
            </DataPoint>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<output>
  <DataPoint>
    <Name>Carrier.Requirements1</Name>
    <Value><![CDATA[Here is the response text]]></Value>
  </DataPoint>
  <DataPoint>
    <Name>Carrier.Requirements2</Name>
    <Value><![CDATA[Here is the response text]]></Value>
  </DataPoint>
  <DataPoint>
    <Name>Carrier.Requirements3</Name>
    <Value><![CDATA[Here is the response text]]></Value>
  </DataPoint>
</output>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTAn

Comment: Thanks a ton Michael  for the timely help.